# How to fix the cas exception - java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: cas

The problem here is the cas is running on k8s cluster. It is deployed using helm chart. The pods crash when i run them through helm charts with the below exception. Same API runs fine in Pre-prod environment.
Compared both environments looks same apart from k8s version:

> Pre-pod : 1.14
>
> Dev: 1.8.4
>
> java.io.FileNotFoundException:/etc/cas/services/RegexRegisteredService-4678622381551994050.json (Read-only file system)

Comment: Is `/etc/cas/services/RegexRegisteredService-4678622381551994050.json` available?

Comment: No that, location isn't available in both the environments!